# Get site owner email details only from Owner group using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, site-collection, sharepoint-on-prem, groups

I need powershell snippet to get site the owner name and email details only from default site owner group

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

$ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain

$ctx = New-Object 'DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext' ([DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain)
$site = get-spweb "xxxxxx"

$groups = $site.Groups | where {$_.Name -eq $site.Title+" Owners"}
$user = @()
foreach($grp in $groups)
{

        $user = Get-SPUser -Web $site -Group $grp 
        write-host $user.name  "`t" $user.LoginName "`t"  $user.Email
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PowerShell script below:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sp"
$sitegroup =$web.SiteGroups |?{$_.Name -EQ "SP Owners"}
foreach($user in $sitegroup.users) {
 "$($user.displayname) `t $($user.LoginName) `t $($user.Email) " | out-file C:\groupmembersreport.csv -append
}
$web.Dispose()
```